# What is the correct way to dispose of a socket returned from accept()?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, klocwork

What is the correct way to dispose of a socket returned from `accept()`?

We run Klocwork over our code and it is complaining about a resource leak even though `closesocket()` is used.  Is this likely to be a false positive or is there a better/correct way to dispose of the returned socket?

There's an example for `accept()` in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526(v=vs.85).aspx) but it does not include any clean up.

Comment: Is there a chance that your code could **not** end up calling closesocket() after accepting the connection? For example, does it throw any exceptions that would cause closesocket() to not be called (and hence cause a resource leak)? Static code analysis can identify these "early exits" or changes of execution flow that may not be immediately obvious by reading the code.

Comment: No, it flags up those separately, e.g. three different code paths = three different resource leak flags.

Comment: The MSDN code is buggy. 'closesocket(ListenSocket);' is called in two places.  One of those should have closed the accept socket.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to dispose of a socket returned from `accept` is to call `closesocket` on it.

Either your code does not always call `closesocket` for some reason, or this is a false positive.